# Functions, lists, python

Tags: python, list, count, symbols

guys. I need to write a programme(function + main programme), which collects words, puts them into one list, then counts symbols in words and if has more symbols than number N, puts it into list2. Then I need to print out the second list. This is what I've got so far:

---

```
def WordsInLists(word, symbols, number):
    list1 = [word]
    list2 = [len.word > n]
    return(list2)

list1 = []
list2 = []
howmany = int(input("How many words will you write?"))
n = int(input("What will the n number be?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
        word = (input("Write the word "))
        list1 = list1 + [word]
        if len.word > n:
            list2 = list2 + [word]
        result = WordsInLists(list2) 
        print(result)
```

---

what should i do next or what should i change?

Comment: This code has lots of errors. I think you should read a python tutorial first.

Comment: What does your code not yet output that it should? That's a good thing to add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you want:

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
howmany = int(input("How many words will you write?"))
n = int(input("What will the n number be?"))
for i in range(0, howmany, 1):
        word = raw_input("Write the word ")
        list1 = list1 + [word]
        if len(word) > n:
            list2 = list2 + [word]
print list2
```

Answer (score 0):

(This assumes Python 3.x):

```
def get_int(prompt):
    while True:
        try:
            return int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:  # not an int
            pass

def main():
    wordlen = get_int("How many words to enter? ")

    words = input("Please enter the words, separated by spaces:\n").split()
    list1, list2 = words[:wordlen], words[wordlen:]

    print("Leftover words: {}".format(", ".join(list2)))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```